# Can I change which app launches when I put my phone in the media dock?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, car-dock

Samsung Desk Home can auto-launch when the phone is placed in the media dock, but it kinda stinks. I have alternatives, like Custom Car Home, but can't see any way to get them to launch.

The standard way of clearing the defaults in "Manage Applications" is greyed out.

My device is rooted, and I run Tasker, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I can't give you any help with the root part since I've never done it but I could let you know what to look out for if you want this action to occur with another app.

Pretty much when you plug the phone into the car dock... an `Intent`is created. If an app like Custom Car Home or another other associates itself with that `Intent` then the user will receive a selection dialog asking them which app they would like to launch for that intent/action.

If at the moment the only thing that happens is the Samsung Desk Home is automatically launched, then this is probably because Custom Car Home has not associated itself with that particular `Intent`.

From the sounds of what Tasker can do (and I hear it can do a heck of a lot) this should be manageable through it. Try to set up an app launch on a specific condition. That condition is when the phone is docked into the car dock.

Tasker will then associate itself with that `Intent` and fire off your desired app.

Hope some of that was a little useful. Sorry I couldn't be much help.

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience with this on the developer side of things (I'm the developer of [Car Dashboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.mandaria.cardashboardfree&feature=search_result)).

Basically, the application has to support the CAR_DOCK intent. Then, when you dock your phone in a car dock, the phone will go into car mode and it will automatically launch the application.  The very first time it launches, you will be presented with a list of multiple "Car Home" like apps to choose from and you can optionally choose one of them to be the default.  This works exactly the same way as switching to a new Home Launcher.

Note: however, that your dock must have a magnet (or similar) to activate the car mode.

However, it could be possible there is something in the Samsung's version of the OS that could be preventing you from launching other kinds of Car Home replacement apps.